# Make Chrome Extension Browser Action Popup bigger than browser window

Tags: google-chrome-extension, popupwindow, browser-action

In FireFox extensions, the Panel/Popup that opens on the Toolbar sizes itself outside the browser window, if needed, so that we see every populated elements in the panel. In Chrome however, the popup/panel is only drawn until the browser window's boundaries. So, if the user resizes the browser window small enough, you don't see the entire popup.

I checked the documentation and couldn't find anything. Is there anything that can be done to show the entire popup?

Comment: Why do you think if user resizes the browser window then he won't see the entire popup? In fact if the user resized the browser window small, the entire popup still shows. I have written a sample extension with popup page and verified that. If you still meet the issue, could you please attach a screenshot in the post?

Comment: Maximized: http://oi63.tinypic.com/2mgwju0.jpg

Smaller Window: http://oi67.tinypic.com/jfusqq.jpg

Comment: see here: http://i68.tinypic.com/14kaczc.png, google translator just show the entire popup. Which chrome version do you use and could you share some code for your extension?

Comment: I am pretty sure I am on the latest Google Chrome. Can you send me the link for that extension, will check the source.

Comment: This seems to be OS-dependent. I can reproduce this on Linux, Haibara's screenshot appears to be from Win10, and Shahid's screenshot is from.. something else I'm not even sure is Windows, since it's not the default shell.

Comment: I am on Windows 7 Performance Setting. FF does it everywhere. I hope there is some setting we can config to get it in Chrome, I hope

Comment: Yes, I'm on Windows 10, and the extension is just official Google Translate. But it seems that is not important since I just wrote a sample extension with nothing else, the popup will never be cropped. Maybe it is really OS-dependent as @Xan said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be OS-dependent (can be reproduced on Linux and Win7, but not Win10).

As an extension author, there is nothing you can do to control it, this is just how the browser renders its content. You could [submit a bug report](https://crbug.com/new).